# Schengen tourist and student visa

Tags: schengen-visas, applications, ghanaian-citizens

I need to visit a friend in Greece from 1st July to 14th July and also I have a summer classes to attend in Spain from 14th July to 27 July , how do I go about it please ?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: I’m from Ghana, Africa

Comment: The information on how to apply should be available from the Greek and Spanish embassies in your country. Do you have a specific question on how to apply, after having done your research?